# How to improve this Entity Framework Core query?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am writing a web application which is readonly, I mean data is read from a database and presented in the UI, so my BLL service methods consist mainly of linq queries like:

```
return context.SomeLinqQuery
```

If I need some calculation I do it within `Select()` method and I wonder is it correct?

The other question is - is it a better way to write below example query? I would like to write the code in line with good practices and I am not sure if putting everything in `Select()` is one of them.

I wonder too, if calling `_context` within `Select()` is wrong or not. If it is wrong, how can I resolve it? Should I load `SomeProperty` in additional loop?

```
_context.SomeEntity
        .Where(some condition)
        .Select(x => new MyModel()
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    Name = x.Name,
                    SomeProperty = x.Status == 1
                        ? _context.DbViewModel.Where(condition).Select...
                        : _context.AnotherDbViewModel.Where(condition).Select...
                });
```

Comment: It isn't wrong but you shouldn't need to do that in a correctly projected domain

Answer (score 1):

> *If I need some calculation I do it within Select() method and I wonder is it correct?*

Yes! Correct! as long as **EF Core** is able to convert the expression generated by your `LINQ` query into `T-SQL`.

> *The other question is - is it a better way to write below example query? I would like to write the code in line with good practices and I am not sure if putting everything in `Select()` is one of them.*

It will depend on the relationship between your entities. Better to build the query using navigation properties.

> *I wonder too, if calling `_context` within `Select()` is wrong or not. If it is wrong, how can I resolve it? Should I load SomeProperty in additional loop?*

Nothing wrong if **EF Core** is able to evaluate the query in database level.

Answer (score 1):

The way to improve EF Query is to let DB do all Query and return expected view directly .

I cannot contribute more code, but you code should simliar like this:

```
_context.SomeEntity
    .Join(DbViewModel,condition)...
    .Join(AnotherDbViewModel,condition)...
    .Where(some condition)
    .Select({
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = x.Name,
                SomeProperty = x.SomePropety.
            })
```

Another solution is to use [DBQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbquery-1?view=efcore-3.1), [Here](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/322/query-types-in-entity-framework-core) is a good example. and also, use [ExecuteSqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlcommand?view=efcore-3.0) or [FromSQL](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/query-types)

if your LINQ is very complex, you can also use [CompiledQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/compiled-queries-linq-to-entities) to improve more.